# Unable to extract scanned pdf using TesseractOCRConfig Apache Tika

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, ocr, apache-tika

My pdf contains scanned images and I want to extract text from it.

What I tried : I tried with AutoDetectParsers but no output.

I followed the solution provided in [Apache Tika extract scanned PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354209/apache-tika-extract-scanned-pdf-files?answertab=active#tab-top) and also Apache Tika Jira at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1729 but getting empty string without any error.

My configuration : Win 7 64-bit OS, JDK 1.8.0_45.

**Any kind of help is welcome.**

Comment: Do you have Tesseract installed and at the location given in your config? Did you try following the [Tika Troubleshooting Guide](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/Troubleshooting%20Tika)?

Comment: @Gagravarr I am using maven to install all jars which includes Tesseract. I have taken a look at the Troubleshooting guide for _No Content Extracted problem_. I have used the most recent version(1.13) of the Apache-tika-app.jar and tried to use the GUI to check the extraction but no output.

Comment: Tesseract is not a Java library, so Maven won't help you. You need to download and install the native program for your operating system

Comment: @Gagravarr I don't want to use any software for this. I want to use TesseractOCR java api which can be used inside my java application. Anyway just for fun, I installed tesseract desktop app and tried my pdf, its extracting some incorrect words.

Comment: Tesseract is a native program you have to download and install separately. All Tika ships is the appropriate wrappers around Tesseract to enable it to be used if installed

Comment: @Gagravarr Can I exctract text from a scanned pdf without installing any native program in my system? If No, then it will drag me into a dependency of a native program to run my java application which I want to avoid.

Comment: Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks for your help. I have installed Tesseract and tried to run tesseract from tika using `new TesseractOCRConfig().setTesseractPath(tesseractFolder);`. I can easily extract text from images, pdf containing single image but not from pdfs where multiple images are present. I am not getting any error but no output.

Comment: This helped me [link](https://github.com/ICIJ/node-tika/issues/14) in solving the issue. The issue was : _Tika dropped support for extracting TIFF images from PDFs in 1.13_ and for that we need to add one more dependency `<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
   <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.1</version>
  </dependency>`. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Steps to follow to solve this :

1. Install Tesseract in your system using 'tesseract-ocr-setup-3.05.00dev.exe' for Windows from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr-alt/files/ and set its location in your config.

   Java code :

   ```
   Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
   BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
   TesseractOCRConfig config = new TesseractOCRConfig();
   config.setTesseractPath(tPath);
   PDFParserConfig pdfConfig = new PDFParserConfig();
   pdfConfig.setExtractInlineImages(true);
   pdfConfig.setExtractUniqueInlineImagesOnly(false); // set to false if pdf contains multiple images.
   ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();
   parseContext.set(TesseractOCRConfig.class, config);
   parseContext.set(PDFParserConfig.class, pdfConfig);
   //need to add this to make sure recursive parsing happens!
   parseContext.set(Parser.class, parser);
   ```
2. Maven dependencies :

`<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.levigo.jbig2</groupId>
        <artifactId>levigo-jbig2-imageio</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>`

I think it may be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Beware of the licensing implications of using levigo and jai.  If they were Apache 2.0 compatible, we would have embedded them.