# Apache Solr does not index scanned PDFs

Tags: java, solr, lucene, apache-tika

I would like to index scanned PDF files. I have installed **Solr 6.3.0**, **tesseract 3.04**, **leptonica 1.74** on Centos 6. I have configured my solrconfig according to [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika).

I have tested tesseract and solr for png, jpg and every thing looks fine. But when I try to index scanned PDF files , Solr does not index scanned image only extract pdf comment message ([sample document](http://solutions.weblite.ca/pdfocrx/scansmpl.pdf)). (DefaultParser and PDFParser used according to index response)

After that I Googled problem and I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354209/apache-tika-extract-scanned-pdf-files) (I tested, it works!) however I could not convert Java code to Xml configuration. How should I set that java code to Xml configuration file?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Lucene 3.0` to index and search for scanned `pdf` file. I have done using `Lucene 3.0` to index scanned `pdf` file and search most frequently repeated words in the scanned `pdf`.