# Slowness in extracting scan PDF using Apache Tika + Tesseract

Tags: java, performance, ocr, tesseract, apache-tika

From [Apache Tika extract scanned PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354209/apache-tika-extract-scanned-pdf-files), it works perfectly fine for scan document. But problem is, it is taking too much time as well as CPU utilization.

In my case, `15 MB` file having `23 pages` takes around `~4.5 minute` which is too high. Please find below my working code,

```
Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

TesseractOCRConfig config = new TesseractOCRConfig();
PDFParserConfig pdfConfig = new PDFParserConfig();
pdfConfig.setExtractInlineImages(true);

ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();
parseContext.set(TesseractOCRConfig.class, config);
parseContext.set(PDFParserConfig.class, pdfConfig);
//need to add this to make sure recursive parsing happens!
parseContext.set(Parser.class, parser);

Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
parser.parse(inputStream, handler, metadata, parseContext);
String content = handler.toString();
```

How can I make it more optimized/faster? Any suggestions?

Comment: If you turn off Tesseract OCR, how much faster does it get?

Comment: Yes, It is very fast without it but does not extract text from Scan PDF. I have implemented earlier without tesseract.

`AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
parser.parse(stream, handler, new Metadata(), new ParseContext());
String content = handler.toString();`

Comment: Sounds like your problem isn't Tika then, it's how to get Tesseract to perform decently, and that's likely to depend on your tessseract version and config and OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gagravarr mentioned in comment, this is not a `Tika` slowness, since `Tesseract` is CPU consuming process.

To handle it, I have separated this process on another server, using `FIFO` method. So that only one file is processed at a time.